# Like Operator with Variable in sql server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

my stored

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDataByLikeFun]
    @TblName nvarchar(max),@FieldName nvarchar(max),@ValParam nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
declare @TAblE nvarchar(max);
set @ValParam='LIKE ''%'+@ValParam+'%'

    set @TAblE = 'Select * From ' + @TblName + ' WHERE ' + @FieldName+@ValParam
    exec(@TAblE)
END
```

Display Error

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '%d%'.
>
> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '%d%'.

any one solved it

Answer (score 2):

```
set @ValParam='LIKE ''%'+@ValParam+'%'
```

change to

```
set @ValParam=' LIKE ''%'+@ValParam+'%'''
```

add space bar in front of LIKE and close your quotes

Comment: Thank you very much
This is the solution
set @ValParam=' LIKE ''%'+@ValParam+'%'''